# UITableViewCell clear separator

Tags: uitableview

I did like following

```
tableview.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

However, when I add new row , separator will appear like following picture.
[image]

How to remove separator in UITableViewCell ?

Comment: I have same problem on ios 9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it

```
UIView *backView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
tableview.backgroundView = backView;
[backView release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just posting because i found other way.

I used UITableView.separatorColor property and set color same as background color of cell.

It will make it easier for those who are using default cell properties